# Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Tags: android

when i new a project  error  above  occur   i use android studio 3.0 gradle 4.1
thsi is error:

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@stagingUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details

when i click show details   the fllowing is:

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0-beta2/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/74.125.237.0] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Add Google repo https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Answer (score 2):

After much research and headache... Go to File\Settings\Gradle. Deselect the "Offline work" box. Now you can connect and download any necessary or missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 3.0, Android libraries can be directly downloaded with the Google's Maven repository (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven).

So in your top-level `build.gradle` file you can use :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

And you can declare a android library like (in app/build.gradle) :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
}
```

For other libraries (not in Google's repo) you can add `jcenter()` as a repository.

And since Android Gradle Plugin 3.0, configuration compile is deprecated and replaced by implementation (see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).

Comment: it's not a good idea for me  ,   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0' need to download some tools  but in china internet is restricted, not free , i want to use  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' ,  how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can change your gradle configuration to not use `google()` but use `mavenLocal()` (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:maven_local) or some other config (local directory) like explained at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:working_with_repositories

Comment: firstly, thank you answer this question for me , but i am a junior android enginner i can't understand your meaning,  those questions about gradle version and plugin  in their relationship  i have a lot confusion

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything like uncheck Offline gradle, distributionUrl etc.

But adding this in end of `build.gradle` file solved my problem -

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```